# Is it possible to refer to the types of Scala case class constructor arguments?

Tags: scala

My goal is to create a trait that a case class can extend, which can process each constructor argument and then pass them as arguments to a method of the case class.  All of the constructor arguments will be the same type with different type parameters, and the method will take arguments that match the type parameter of each constructor argument.  You can think of it as a pre-processor of the constructor arguments.  For example,

```
case class Foo(input1:Input[Int], input2:Input[String]) extends MagicTrait {
  def run(input1:Int, input2:String) { ... }
}
```

Is this at all feasible?  Is it feasible in a way that isn't terribly ugly (e.g. all reflection)?  Is it possible to refer to the companion object of a case class in a way that is  at all generic across case classes (e.g. a function that takes the output of Companion.unapply())?

Comment: Given a value of type Input[T] how do I get a corresponding value of type T?

Comment: I do know of a way where you intercept the constructor from a trait. May be there is a better approach to what you want. I am assuming, you would want to create MagicTrait because you dont want to repeat this preprocessing code in every class. What kind of preprocessing do you want to do on these constructor arguments?

Comment: A good parallel to my situation would be that each of the arguments is a function, and I want to run each function and then invoke a new function with the output of each the functions.

Comment: So Input[T] can be considered as equivalent to () => T for present purposes?

Comment: Is it essential that the "preprocessing" functionality be mixed into instances, or could it be provided by the case class companion object? If that's so, then can the signature of `run` replace `Foo`s constructor signature?

Comment: Yes, Input[T] can be equivalent to () => T for this discussion.  I'm not sure I understand -- the "preprocessing" functionality could certain be provided by the case class companion object, if there was a way for the companion object to extend a trait that provided a generalized way to do this.  Does that help?  What are you thinking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seeing as an acceptable solution allows the preprocessing functionality to be moved off the instances to an associated object the main remaining difficulty is that you want to be able to abstract over the arity and types (ie. the shape) of your case class constructors. This is possible with the `HList` implementation and polymorphic function values from [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).

First some preliminaries,

```
import shapeless.HList._
import shapeless.Functions._
import shapeless.Poly._
import shapeless.TypeOperators._

// Implementation of your Input wrapper
case class Input[T](value: T)

// Value extractor as a shapeless polymorphic function value
object value extends (Input ~> Id) {
  def default[T](i : Input[T]) = i.value
}
```

We can now define a preprocessor base class which provides an apply method which takes an `HList` of `Input` types, maps the `value` polymorphic function across it (ie. performing the preprocessing) and then passes the resulting `HList` of non-`Input` types to the provided case class constructor (which is given in hlisted form, see below),

```
// Pre-processer base class
abstract class Preprocessor[In <: HList, Out <: HList, R](ctor : Out => R)
  (implicit mapper : MapperAux[value.type, In, Out]) {
    def apply(in : In) = ctor(in map value)
  }
```

Now we define the case class with the post-processing component types,

```
case class Foo(input1 : Int, input2 : String)
```

and add one line of boilerplate,

```
object FooBuilder extends Preprocessor((Foo.apply _).hlisted)
```

(here the Foo companion object factory method is provided as the `Preprocessor` constructor argument in HListed form as required above.)

Now we can construct `Foo` instances using the `FooBuilder`.

```
val foo = FooBuilder(Input(23) :: Input("foo") :: HNil)
```

Unfortunately it isn't (currently) possible to combine the `FooBuilder` object with the `Foo` companion object: if you attempt to have the `Foo` companion extend `Preprocessor` you'll discover that the `Foo` factory method isn't available to be passed as the `Preprocessor` constructor argument.

To illustrate that this solution is really abstracting over type and arity, here's how we might add a second differently shaped case class,

```
case class Bar(input1 : Int, input2 : String, input3 : Boolean)

object BarBuilder extends Preprocessor((Bar.apply _).hlisted)

val bar = BarBuilder(Input(23) :: Input("foo") :: Input(true) :: HNil)
```

Comment: This is a terrific answer!  Thank you so much.  It directly solves my problem, is very complete, and I learned a lot from it and reviewing your shapeless library.

Answer (score 2):

```
case class Input[T](value: T)

trait MagicTrait[T,U] {
   val input1: Input[T]
   val input2: Input[U]
   def run: Unit
}

case class Foo(input1: Input[Int], input2: Input[String]) 
    extends MagicTrait[Int, String] {
  def run = println(input1.value * 2 + input2.value.toUpperCase)
}

scala> val m: MagicTrait[_,_] = Foo(Input(3), Input("hi"))
m: MagicTrait[_, _] = Foo(Input(3),Input(hi))

scala> m.run
6HI
```

edit:

If you want to find the types of the class parameters you can use the fact that case classes extend `Product`:

```
scala> Foo(2, "hi").productIterator.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass).toList
res13: List[java.lang.Class[_]] = 
         List(class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.String)
```

But this uses the reflection you wanted to avoid. This is why we use parameterization.

If you want to return its companion object, I'm not sure you can do this in a useful, type-safe way in the context of case classes, because companion objects don't extend an interface that specifies their extractor methods. You might be able to do something with structural types but it's probable that there's a better way to approach whatever problem it is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: My hope was to refer to the types of the arguments of the case class without having to parameterize the trait on the types of the case class arguments.  And if I was to follow this path, I'll need to create a trait for each arity -- e.g. MagicTrait1 (one argument), MagicTrait2 (two arguments), MagicTrait3, etc.  But maybe there's no better solution?

Comment: What's happened to the Input[_] type constructor here?

Comment: @MilesSabin I've added it to my answer, but it doesn't change anything except to muddy the waters; the point that you can implement a parameterized trait using case class constructor arguments is the same.